Why does my code return the old value after I update the record?
I update a record in the database using Drizzle ORM but the database returns the old value:
export async function updateDailyWord(data: number) {
    const date = new Date(Date.now());
    console.log("new wordId: ", data);
    await db.update(dailyWord)
        .set({
            wordId: data,
            date: `${date.getFullYear()}-
                ${date.getMonth() + 1}-
                ${date.getDate()}`})
        .where(eq(dailyWord.id, 1))

    const updatedRecord = await db.select()
        .from(dailyWord)
        .where(eq(dailyWord.id, 1));
    console.log("Updated record: ", updatedRecord);
}

Cmd log:
new wordId:  2
Updated record:  [ { id: 1, wordId: 3, date: '2024-7-8' } ]

wordId should be 2 instead of 3. I know about the returning method but I don't use it here for better logging. Changing the set and where statement didn't help. Other functions work properly with the database, the problem is in updating the database.

Did you get a solution? I am also experiencing the same issue.
